# how to mock global variable in Mockito

Tags: java, global-variables, mockito, powermock

I have a global variable `global`.

My method has a line:

```
global.getListOfObjects()
```

I am trying to write a unit test and keep getting a NPE on the above line.
How can i mock a global variable?

I am using Mockito and PowerMock.

Comment: Global variable? Could you be more specific?

Comment: an object that is available to any file in the project.

Comment: Do you have any code of that object? And test? Because no one knows whether the object is Singleton, or just static method, or something else.

Comment: what have you tried and failed? Why mocking of `global` is failing in your scenario? which error you get?

Answer (score 1):

These are the things you could do, if I understand your question correctly:

1. Use setter method of that property in your source class.
   `yourSourceClass.setGlobal(somethingYouNeed);`
2. If that is a public member, you can assign that public member value, from your test class. Like: 
   `yourSourceClass.global = <somethingYouNeed>;`

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use must have the mock object of the same class as below

@InjectMock

ABCClass abc;

Now you can set global variable as abc.global = value in the test case where you need this value.